# How can I Inject Behavior into Entity Framework Object Constructors?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

If I have an entity EntityA, which is an Entity Framework object, how would I go about injecting different behavior at time of creation?

These particular entities need to utilize a different strategy for some calculations. I would like to use DI to supply the correct strategy when the object is created. Is there any way to intercept?

Added:
i thinking on the two patterns below (just pseudo to get the point across).

```
        public partial class Entity
    {
          public Entity(ICalculationStrategy strategy)
          {
              _calcStrategy = strategy;
          }
    }

public partial class Entity
        {
              public Entity(ICalculationFactory factory)
              {
                  _calcStrategy = factory.ProvideCalculator(this);
              }
        }
```

Comment: Those two patterns are not significantly different. It still doesn't show what factors determine the strategy to be used by this particular instance.

Comment: That's the tricky part. The way it is done now is they use an Entity attribute(name) which matches the class name to dynamically create the correct calculator instance (Activator). I am not sure if I am thinking about this incorrectly at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Can you pass in the strategy at the time the calculation is performed?

```
myEntity.Calculate(myStrategy);
```

How about invert the relationship between the strategy and the entity?

```
myStrategy.Calculate(myEntity);
```

Or, DI the strategy using property injection?

Comment: Completely inverting the relationship is something I have considered. I am starting to lean that direction the more I think about it. In my case there is actually more than one step/strategy involved in the overall process. A DDD Service object might be the way to go here. It could manage the generation of each strategy and overall workflow, which is identical for all entities.

The only thing that bothers me is that the entities themselves are tied to a specific strategy. I am not sure if there will be any reuse. Each strategy has a specific dataset/parameters it requires. Any ideas? :)

Comment: By paramaters I mean constants really. All strategies don't use the same constants, but there is overlap there.

Answer (score 1):

EntityObjects don't have any constructor defined in their generated code, so you can just add one in a partial class:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntity()
    {
         // Whatever logic to determine your strategy
    }
}
```

How you would go about doing your calculations differently, depends on what *exactly* you're trying to do. If you want to pass extra parameters to the constructor somehow, I don't think you can, so you'll have to work around that.

Also, have you looked at [inheritance](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2007/03/15/inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) in Entity Framework? Based on the value of some column / property, you can have it use a different subclass, which can have different implementations of various business logic, through the use of partial classes with `abstract` and/or `virtual` methods and properties.

Of course, you could change the behavior after the object is instantiated, but I get the feeling that isn't what you want? Could you access the factory in a static way? Either as a static class, method or property?

```
MyFactory.Current = new MyFactory(parameters);

public partial class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntity()
    {
        _calcStrategy = MyFactory.Current.ProvideCalculator(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need something more than a default no params constructor. Essentially I want to inject a strategy at construction time or a factory so the Entity can request the proper strategy. Maybe I'll broaden the scope and explain what I am trying to do. The strategy direction doesn't feel correct.

Comment: Just wanted to add that inheritance doesn't work in this case as every entity will have a slightly different strategy logic.